# .Net PowerShell Invoke tf(TFS) History

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, tfs, version-control

I want to use PowerShell to Automation Invoke 【cd D:/XXXX】&【tf history *】 to change working folder
then get my target TFS change History.

But I have Problem to Invoke tf.

.Net use PowerShell Invoke tf(TFS)

```
public static bool GetFile(string disk, string projectPath, string dateRegion, string fileFullPath)
    {
        bool result = true;
        try
        {
            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershell.AddScript($"{disk}");
                powershell.AddScript(@$"cd {projectPath}");

                powershell.AddScript(@$"tf vc history * /noprompt /recursive /format:detailed /v:D{dateRegion} > {fileFullPath}");

                foreach (PSObject psResult in powershell.Invoke())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(psResult);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("執行結束");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            result = false;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why invoke PowerShell to invoke a program, rather than running the `tf.exe` program directly with the `Process` class?

Comment: Why not use the client libraries for C# to retrieve the information from TFS, instead of using the `tf` executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use it without powershell like here:

```
        string foderPath = "YOUR_WORKSPACE";
        string tfexepath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe";

        var p = Process.Start(
            new ProcessStartInfo(tfexepath, $@"vc history * /noprompt /recursive /format:detailed")
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = foderPath
            }
            );

        p.WaitForExit();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd();
        string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.WriteLine(error);
```